# Change providers value from component code

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I have angular component where I use providers

Here is code

```
    @Component({
  selector: 'app-service-desk-ticket-main-data',
  templateUrl: './service-desk-ticket-main-data.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./service-desk-ticket-main-data.component.scss'],
  providers: [
    UserLinkStatisticService,
    { provide: OPEN_PROFILE_TRACKING_CATEGORY_TOKEN, useValue: STATISTIC.CATEGORY.SERVICE_DESK },
    { provide: OPEN_PROFILE_TRACKING_LOCATION_TOKEN, useValue: STATISTIC.LOCATION.SD_TICKETS_PAGE },
  ],
})
```

in component code I want to change value of `OPEN_PROFILE_TRACKING_LOCATION_TOKEN` related on `@Input` value

Here is pseudo code of Component

```
  export class ServiceDeskTicketMainDataComponent implements OnInit {
  @Input()
  public model: ServiceDeskTicket;

  @Input()
  public isPopup = false;

  @Output() subscriptionChanged = new EventEmitter<void>();

  public readonly unsubscribeTitle =
    'If you unsubscribe, you will only receive notifications when your name is mentioned on this ticket';

  public location: string;

  constructor(
    private serviceDeskService: ServiceDeskService,
    private popupService: PopupService,
    private preloader: PreloaderService,
    private cdr: ChangeDetectorRef,
    private alertService: AlertService,
    private statistic: ServiceDeskStatisticService,
  ) {}

  public ngOnInit(): void {
    this.location = this.isPopup ? STATISTIC.LOCATION.SD_TICKETS_PAGE_POPUP : STATISTIC.LOCATION.SD_TICKETS_PAGE;
  }
}
```

Logic is in `OnInit`. I need same logic, but for provider `useValue`

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what problem you are trying to solve.  You want to change one of your providers dynamically?

Comment: yes, in OnInit @FiniteLooper

Comment: I do not believe it is possible to dynamically change the providers like that.  That happens internally inside Angular before any of your code is called and I do not believe it can be changed after the fact since that would mess with Angular in unpredictable ways.  Why do you need to do this?  If it's just for display in the component you could just choose which value to display like you are already doing.

Comment: I need to change location that will be passed to service, I really think Angular has option to change value @FiniteLooper

Comment: Hmm, well it's not something I'm very familar with.  Does something like [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54209879/how-to-set-config-or-usevalue-for-imported-modules-from-a-component) help?